# Can't install gem nokogiri with 2.3.0p ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, mechanize

Welcome, I tried to install gem mechanize and got stuck at nokogiri gem. Then I tried to install nokogiri gem and got stuck also. Here is my CMD, this doesn't make sense ;/

```
>ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x64-mingw32]

>gem install nokogiri
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.3, >= 1.9.2.
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868318/nokogiri-requires-ruby-version-2-3

Comment: What version of nokogiri are you installing?

Comment: I used gem install nokogiri so I thinks it's the newest one.

Comment: Nothing from listed topic is working

Comment: The error message says you need a ruby version that is **less than** 2.3. It seems to me you need an earlier version of ruby to run that version of nokogiri.

Answer (score 2):

Install the newest version of `Nokogiri`.

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.8.rc2
```

**UPDATE :**

Nokogiri currently requires some special attention on Ruby 2.3 (only):

You need to use the system libraries instead of those bundle with Nokogiri by default. To achieve this using bundler, please switch from bundle install to the following commands instead.

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

Comment: As I wrote about - it didn't work. nokogiri in newest version isn't working with 2.3.0 on win x64.

Comment: @Iwo okay got it, try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Downcars is right, silly me.
Answer:

> The error message says you need a ruby version that is less than 2.3. It seems to me you need an earlier version of ruby to run that version of nokogiri. – Dawcars